# Swift 3 Breaks Cell For Row At Index Path

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

This code was from a now inactive tutorial that helped me load in data to a table view. Since the tutorial was written in Swift 2.0, I believe that this was changed in Swift 3. I know that the override function itself was changed, which I handled. But now, it brings me a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error.

**Update:** I have tried multiple things including creating a custom class for the cell. I still either get the same error I listed above, or a `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT` error on the first line of my App Delegate file. Creating a breakpoint hasn't helped me because I know where the error is coming from.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


struct postStruct {
    let title : String!
    let message : String!
}

class LoggedInController: UITableViewController {

    var posts = [postStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = snapshotValue!["title"] as? String

            let message = snapshotValue!["message"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(postStruct(title: title, message: message), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

        post()
    }

    func post(){

        let title = "Title"
        let message = "Message"

        let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title" : title as AnyObject,
                                           "message": message as AnyObject]

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    return cell!
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** Here is the new code I used. It's not pretty and only gets the title.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].message
        return cell!
    } else {
        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        label1?.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
        label2?.text = posts[indexPath.row].message
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow) I believe the only thing that has changed is the method signature of your func, so just start typing `cellFor` and the autocomplete would pop something likely

Comment: The most efficient solution is to create a **custom** cell with IBOutlets in Interface Builder. The `viewWithTag` way is outdated at least since Xcode 6.

Comment: @vadian I've set the cell type to custom. I'm not sure how to do it with IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dequeueReusableCell`, you are accessing cell which doesn't exists. To make your code work change the below line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
```

To

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: This gives me a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT on the first line of my app delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
 {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    return cell
}
```

Edited

Make Sure you did these things

**UITableViewController**

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,     forCellReuseIdentifier:"catCell" )
let catNib : UINib = UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCategoryCell",  bundle: nil)
self.tableView.register(catNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCategoryCell")
```

In `cellForRowAt indexPath`

```
let cell : OPM_AlarmTableViewCategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"OPM_AlarmTableViewCategoryCell" ) as! OPM_AlarmTableViewCategoryCell!
cell.categoryLabel?.text = "Some Text"
return cell
```

**UITableviewCell.XIB**
Hope u did these things
    [image: Custom Class]
    [image: TableViewCell]
    [image: Outlet]

**UITableviewCell**
    [image: Tableviewcell code]
Make sure the dot appears so that the `@IBOutlet` is connected with the 
xib label

Comment: This gives me a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on `let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!`

Comment: Just tell me if u are using story board or not.

Comment: I am to make the prototype cells.

Comment: So u made cells in xib ?

Comment: I don't have the category label outlet option on my xib.

Comment: U need to select the uitavleviewcell in xib then click reference, u will have category label there select the label and connect it to the label u created in xib file

Comment: I know how to do it. I do not have it.

Comment: @SteveHalla Hi, did you manage to resolve this problem. I am working on the same thing, trying to convert the code from Swift 2 to Swift 3, and without any success :-(

Any help would be very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Ok this code `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")` produces an optional called `cell` that may or may not contain a a valid instance of UITableViewCell. Optionals in Swift are a way to safeguard against nil values, you can read more about optionals here: [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional)

On the first run when your table view wants to load its data it calls all the required methods of your `UITableViewDataSource`. The first run is a critical one because there aren't any instances of the UITableViewCell the table view can dequeue ***yet***. To solve your problem you have to do something similar to the code below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "New value"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "New value"
        return cell!
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "" //reset value
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "" // resetValue
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "New value"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "New value"
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Code similar to the one above are usually used to programmatically add an instance of `UITableViewCell`. However, if you used interface builder to add a prototype cell use the `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)` method to dequeue your cells in which case it does not return an optional and you do not need to do all the if / else blocks.
Something else I wanted to mention about your code is finding sub views buy their ID will not produce a very object oriented code and that maybe the source of your errors where the compiler can not find the sub views. The better way would be to use one of the built in instances of UITableViewCell such as `.default` or alliteratively you could subclass the said class and make your very own custom cells.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Edited the code make sure you use the update version.

Comment: This did not help. I am using a interface builder to add a prototype cell. This is where I got the tags from. However I did try your code but it returned a `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT` error on my app delegate.

Comment: Tags can also be set programmatically. It seems like the problem here is not creating cells, because the code I provided is very standard. The app delegate run time error is an extremely generic error so I would suggest to set a breakpoint on your code to stop execution just before the app crashes. To do this select your breakpoint navigator. On the bottom left you will see a + sign click on that and choose an exception breakpoint. You will be presented with options to further modify the break point. All the default setting are ok. Run you code again and see where the code breaks. @SteveHalla

Comment: It breaks when it gets to this line `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)`