# Downloading json from Firebase and populating TableView Swift 3

Tags: json, uitableview, download, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to convert the code below from Swift 2 to Swift 3 but am coming across errors, some of which I have remedied but there are some which I have not been able to solve. Any help would be much appreciated.The App is crashing when it shows the TableView at the line

```
   let property = snapshotValue!["property"] as? String
```

With the error message: *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

There is also a problem with post.self with the message *'expression of type post. Type is unused*

```
struct  post {
    let property :  String!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var posts = [post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in

        var snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let property = snapshotValue!["property"] as? String
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


        self.posts.insert(post(property: property), at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
post.self

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return posts.count
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
     label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].property
    return cell!
}
```

}

Many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

I had not realised that despite my search, this exact question had already been asked and answered.

The person who posted the question updated his code to the answer. It worked for me :-) The link to the page on StackOverflow is:

[Swift 3 Breaks Cell For Row At Index Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797508/swift-3-breaks-cell-for-row-at-index-path/40801241?noredirect=1)